# Update rows in table with id from row before in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, update, subquery

Say I have a table like this:

```
| id | grp   | time_added | previous_id |
|----|-------|------------|-------------|
| 1  | 1     | 5          | null        |
| 2  | 1     | 8          | null        |
| 3  | 2     | 9          | null        |
| 4  | 1     | 12         | null        |
| 5  | 2     | 15         | null        |
```

(time_added is actually a date, but numbers are used here for readability)

I want to update the `previous_id` of each row so that it's equal to the `id` of the previous row in the same group `grp` sorted by `time_added`.

This means that after running the update query, the table above should look like:

```
| id | grp   | time_added | previous_id |
|----|-------|------------|-------------|
| 1  | 1     | 5          | null        |
| 2  | 1     | 8          | 1           |
| 3  | 2     | 9          | null        |
| 4  | 1     | 12         | 2           |
| 5  | 2     | 15         | 3           |
```

---

What I have so far is the following query:

```sql
UPDATE the_table r
SET previous_id = sub.id
FROM (
  SELECT id, time_added, grp
  FROM the_table
  ORDER BY time_added DESC
) sub
WHERE (
  r.grp = sub.grp
  AND sub.time_added < r.time_added
);
```

However, I suspect the `ORDER BY` of the subquery does not do what I want it to, and the `previous_id` is set to the id of a random row below it, not the one strictly below it.

See [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6377a/1) fiddle for an example of what happens. Row 3 is given a `previous_id` of 1, when it should be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired result by using LAG() function.

```
select
    id,
    grp,
    time_added,
    lag(id) over (partition by grp order by grp, time_added) previous_id
from
    tbl;
```

You can update in this way:

```
with x as
(
    select
        id,
        lag(id) over (partition by grp order by grp, time_added) previous_id
    from
        tbl
)
update tbl
set    
    previous_id = x.previous_id
from
    x
where
    x.id = tbl.id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=711c85c31448a7b32e748eb5d327ab16)*

Comment: You can remove grp from `order by grp, id`

Comment: Thank you for the tip.

What solved my issue was:

```
UPDATE the_table r
SET previous_id = sub.p_id
FROM (
  SELECT id, time_added, grp, lag(id) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY time_added) p_id
  FROM the_table
) sub
WHERE sub.id = r.id;
```

Comment: @McNets, since ordering is done per grp, I don't see how ordering by grp should matter? Can you give an example where it will make a difference?

Comment: @Lennart sorry, you're right. In this case order is set by `time_added`, may be I misread the question.